# how to integrate bugzilla and HP quality center?

Tags: bugzilla, integrate, hp-quality-center

I'm working on integrating Bugzilla with HP Qc.  I'm performing this by using perl script by directly manipulating the database using sql commands.  I want to use the web services of Bugzilla. I have gone through the Bugzilla webservice API but tat wasn't enough to get started. I'm a beginner and this is the first project of my career. How do I go about this?

Comment: Would it be better to retag this as hp and hp-quality-center since it's a product made by HP?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Perl script [bz_webservice_demo.pl](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.2/en/html/api/contrib/bz_webservice_demo.html) in Bugzilla's contrib directory, it shows how to talk to Bugzilla via XMLRPC.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do:

1. Export defects from Bugzilla into a spreadsheet and upload it into Quality Center
2. Use the Open Test Architecture API (OTAClient.dll) to update defects in Quality Center
3. Use the [HP Synchronization Server and build an adapter](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc110/sync/almsynchronizer/index.html)

Using the HP Synchronizer is probably the only "real" way to do it.  Though you could potentially build your own sync mechanism, potentially using just OTA and a message queue.

There may be an existing adapter available from [proficom-ag](http://proficom.de) based on a [presentation](http://www.vivit-tqa.org/docs/Vivit09_K05_Jaehnig_ProfiCom.pdf) I found via a web search